# Frontend: Description Showing in Front of All Cards Instead of Inside Each Card 'reactjs&tailwind'

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, tailwind-css

I'm currently working on a React frontend where I have a grid of cards displaying various experiences. Each card is supposed to show details like period, company, role, and description. However, I'm encountering an issue where the description appears in front of all cards instead of inside each respective card.

Here's the relevant JSX code:

```
<div className='grid grid-cols-4 gap-5 mt-5'>
                {experiences.map((experience) => {
                    return (<div className='shadow border p-5 border-gray-400 flex flex-col'>
                        <h1 className='text-primary text-xl font-bold'>{experience.period}</h1><br/>
                        <h1>Company: {experience.company}</h1><br/>
                        <h1>Role: {experience.title}</h1><br/>
                        <p>Description: {experience.description}</p><br/>
                        <div className='flex justify-end gap-5 mt-5'>
                            <button className='px-5 py-2 bg-red-500 text-white '
                            onClick={() => {
                                onDelete(experience);
                            }}
                            >Delete</button>
                            <button className='px-5 py-2 bg-primary text-white '
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setselectedItemForEdit(experience);
                                    setshowAddEditModal(true);
                                    setType('edit')
                                }}
                            >Edit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>)
                })}
            </div>
```

output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPyrY.png)

Comment: You have a problem with CSS , just search for word-wrap
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss3_word-wrap